# Language Change Using JSON

Tags: jquery, json

I wrote a code where a JQuery Ajax will call the JSON and based on the radio buttons selected, the field values should change. The Code is as follows

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test.json",
    data : "",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType : 'application/json',
    success: function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    try{
            console.log(response.lang.english.login);
            console.log(response.lang.arabic.login);

        }
        catch(Exception){
        }
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, exception) { CRDates
    alert("Error");
    }

});
```

and the JSON file is as follows

```
  {"lang":
     {
"english":{
    "login":"Login"
},
"arabic":{
    "login":"دخول"
           }}
          and the HTML is as follows
```

Choose a Language:

```
  <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="Language" value="Arabic"/>
 <label for="radio-choice-1">Arabic</label>

    <input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="Language" value="Arabic"/>
    <label for="radio-choice-4">English</label>

<div><label for="declarationNumber" style="margin-left:30px"><b>Login</div><br>
```

Now I want to change the language based on the seleted radio button. I could'nt get the value of the radio button. For example if I check on arabic, it should change to arabic
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to get the value of the radio button

```
var selectedVal = "";
var selected = $("input[type='radio']:checked");
if (selected.length > 0) {
  selectedVal = selected.val();
}
```

Comment: I got the radio button value but the problem is where to write this function? because the JSON values will come while the page is loaded but where should I call this function>

Comment: Use a button after the selection of the checkbox.So on click of the button the function is called

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

[Working demo](http://www.jqversion.com/#!/ugdURt5)

Javascript

```
var languages = null;

$(document).ready(function(){
    // do your ajax here and set the languages variable
languages = {"lang":
                {
                    "english":{
                        "login":"Login"
                    },
                    "arabic":{
                        "login":"دخول"
                    }
                }
            };

  $('input[name="radio-choice"]').click(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#login-label b').text(languages.lang[$(this).data('language')].login);
    }
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="Language-arabic" data-language="arabic" value="Arabic"/>
<label for="radio-choice-1">Arabic</label>

<input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="Language-english" data-language="english" value="English"/>
<label for="radio-choice-4">English</label>

<div><label for="declarationNumber" style="margin-left:30px" id="login-label"><b>Login</b></label></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir but is it possible to implement this if there are multiple labels, and I tried putting the ajax method but its not working, can you please help?